# How to prevent a Laravel security leak where an API returns not found when you are not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, api, security, uuid

Lets say I have the following route to display a specific user in an API point, that is protected via some authentication middle:

```
Route::get('/v1/user/{user}', 'Api\V1\UserController@show')->middleware('can:show,user');
```

Assume my database is filled with just a handfull records. Then, going to the route **without** a credential:

- `/api/v1/user/1` will give me `403 UNAUTHORIZED`
- `/api/v1/user/999999` will give me `404 NOT FOUND`

In this setup, any visitor can find out how many users I have, by just poking around and trying some routes. Moreover, they can also find out the primary identifier (the id) of these users. This is something I would like to hide from a business perspective, but also from a security perspective.

An appoach that partially addresses this issue, is using UUID's. UUIDs are universally unique alpha-numeric identifiers that are 36 characters long, and [Laravel supports the use of these on your models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys). This will hide the amount of records our have, and make it hard to find existing records. However, since it is still statistically possible to find records by just brute forcing, I feel this is not the correct answer to this problem.

So, how can I prevent a Laravel security leak where API returns not found when you are not authenticated?

Comment: u can follow github's technique and show 404 instead of unauthorized, so the attackers don't know if the resource actually exists or not

Comment: @ericmp That is indeed something I am considering. An answer proposing this solution should include the implementation to demonstrate how that is done. In Laravel, is this done via a configuration, auth change, or a different implementation of controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow GitHub's technique and return a `404` (Not found) instead of `403` (Unauthorized).

This way, attackers don't know if the resource actually exists or not.

To achieve this in Laravel, you may do it like this:
In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, create/edit the method called `render()` and check if the status code is `403`. If so, throw a `404` instead.

```php
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception->getStatusCode() === 403) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

If you want to test it, just add this test route in `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return abort(403); // should return a 404
});
```

Resources:

- [Related topic's discussion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82399/is-it-ok-to-give-status-404-to-unauthorized-users)
- [Method render documentation](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Debug/ExceptionHandler.html#method_render)

Answer (score 2):

```php
// Path: app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/UserController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return $user;
    }
}
```

```php
// Path: app/User.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

```php
// Path: routes/api.php
<?php

Route::get('/v1/user/{user}', 'Api\V1\UserController@show')->middleware('can:show,user');
```

```php
// Path: app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

```php
// Path: app/Http/Middleware/Can.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class Can
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|string  $arguments
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ability, ...$arguments)
    {
        if (Gate::denies($ability, $arguments)) {
            throw new AuthorizationException(
                'This action is unauthorized.', null, Response::deny()
            );
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```php
// Path: app/Http/Kernel.php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\Can;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => Can::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

```php
// Path: app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/UserControllerTest.php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Api\V1;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function testShow()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->getJson("/api/v1/user/{$user->id}");

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function testShowUnauthorized()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->getJson("/api/v1/user/{$user->id}");

        $response->assertStatus(403);
    }

    public function testShowUnauthorizedWithPolicy()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->getJson("/api/v1/user/{$user->id}");

        $response->assertStatus(403);
    }
}
```

```php
// Path: app/Policies/UserPolicy.php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User  $model
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show(User $user, User $model)
    {
        return $user->id === $model->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. That is a lot of lines of code. Could you explain the most interesting part(s) how it works?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to generate a slug.
Then you can use the slug instead of the id.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but you can then still differentiate between an existing record and a non-existing record when you are not authenticated, thus the security issue remains.